# Basic MongoDB -- how to select * from a table

Tags: mongodb

This is an example of a document I have:

```
{ _id: "Y5nf7Hh6DskxjjMEZ", 
  createdAt: ISODate("2015-01-05T01:58:09.365Z"), 
  email_hash: "1basdfkjasldfsomethinghashedalsdjf23", 
  emails: [ 
         { address: "hermione@gmail.com", 
           verified: false } 
          ], 
   isAdmin: false, 
   karma: 0, 
   postCount: 0, 
   profile: {  email: "hermione@gmail.com", 
               notifications: { users: false, 
                                posts: false 
                              }, 
               subscribed: true, 
               username: "hermione" 
             }, 
   services: { password: { bcrypt: "$23098somethingencrypted23094" }, 
   resume: { loginTokens: [] } }, 
   slug: "Hermione", 
   status: { online: false }, 
   username: "hermione"
 }
```

I'm trying to return *all the e-mail addresses*  something equivalent to the idea of `SELECT emails.address FROM users` or `SELECT profile.email FROM users;`

How do I do this with Mongo?

Comment: if you know that this is such a basic question, you might have thought that other people had it before. Have you tried to search how to achieve it?

Comment: `db.collection.find({'profile.email':1})`?

Comment: I finally figured out part of it after finding http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/, but I got confused because db.users.find({},{profile.email:1 }).limit(1) wasn't working... and *then* I realized, from looking at your comment, that I was missing apostrophes. Decided to ask in case people had more obvious solutions to this than what I was thinking. Thanks!

Comment: @LNA instead of `unwind` this `find({},{"emails.address":1,"profile.email":1})` also work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because field **emails** is an array, I suggest you to use `$unwind(aggregation)` to get **emails** out of the array first,then combine the result with `$project(aggregation)`, to get `SELECT emails.address FROM users`

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $unwind : "$emails" },{$project:{ field1:1,field2:1,... ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like people think that this is a proper question, so here is your solution:

```
var mails = [];
db.a.find({},{'emails.address' : 1}).forEach(function(o){
    for (var i = 0; i < o.emails.length; i++){
        mails.push(o.emails[i].address)
    }
})
```

put this in mongoshell and mails will have all your email addresses. Note that each document should have at least one address. If this is not the case, add one line which verifies it.